# How to set-up different URLs for yii frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

For example, if I want `localhost/basic.com` for the front-end and `localhost/basic/admin` for the back-end.

I am new to the framework, however, it seems really interesting.

Please help.

I have watched tutorials and all but none seem to cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following .htaccess

```
Options FollowSymLinks
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # the main rewrite rule for the frontend application
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(backend/web|admin)
    RewriteRule !^frontend/web /frontend/web%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

    # redirect to the page without a trailing slash (uncomment if necessary)
    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
    #RewriteRule ^(admin)/ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # the main rewrite rule for the backend application
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
    RewriteRule ^admin(.*) /backend/web/$1 [L]

    # if a directory or a file of the frontend application exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/frontend/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . /frontend/web/index.php [L]

    # if a directory or a file of the backend application exists, use the request directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/backend/web
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule . /backend/web/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(htaccess|htpasswd|svn|git)
    RewriteRule \.(htaccess|htpasswd|svn|git) - [F]
</IfModule>
```

FUll configurations can be found at: https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-advanced-one-domain-config

Comment: which directory should i put the .htaccess file in

Comment: Place it on the root directory. I suppose it is 'localhost/basic.com' in your case

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated